# Typescript Mapped Type. Resulting property type in is not calculated if mix of Generic used

Tags: typescript, typeerror, mapped-types

I try to build generic method that accepts Mapped Type called `QueryParamObject` and partially reads its properties:

`QueryParamObject` accepts any type and results to a type where all properties are either string[] or string:

```
export type QueryParamObject<TInput> = {
    [key in keyof TInput]: TInput[key] extends Array<string | number> ? string[] : string;
};
```

It works perfect when I use concrete types:

```
type Concrete = {
    numberProp: number;
    numberArray: number[];
    stringArray: string[];
}

function read(arg: QueryParamObject<Concrete>): void {
    const arr1: string[] = arg.numberArray;
    const prop1: string = arg.numberProp;

    // const arr2: number[] = arg.numberArray; //will have type error
}
```

But everything breaks and resulting type of each property becomes `string[] | string` when I add a Generic:

```
function read<TExtra>(arg: QueryParamObject<TExtra & Concrete>): void {
    const arr1: string[] = arg.numberArray; //Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string[]'
}
```

[image: When using a Generic type compiler cannot calculate the resulting type properly]

[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCKBXYVEAUCGU+AtgPIBGAVsAMYwA8AKgJIB2YGMAfHALxwBvAFBxRcANoBrYIjgBLVnGmIIAMzgt2nALoAuDWw4wpM7XFAxgrACYBnOAEEoRRPVswoCgOZwAPnFYMYnJsHgB+OHdPVi9xM30o7wBuIQBfFKEkFDgAYQhWGihgSz5BETFA4OxcKAgwfUqQqBSxAKCmpxcG9uw4lrFEmM78RASPbz60oSFVDAKYOXy4IvxrADkIAHErbDkaAApCL31MbDxCEgpqOno8gqLLLgBKfQA3CDlrMtaafPc4QhQACMY2isTM-COADpGthhoh+qJfqx-mBamAQZFxjFStDYVAanUMj8-vBAQAmbpVKBxXFQLwwnpQeEpVIzOZ0RaKFbWbasXY0JgAURAHnwXEO9JOWBwBCIZCotAYjBFYrgADJcvlCsVgM83h8vsISSiyc5MYNwXSGfiWeUkaS4Gi6hbsT5IfTGdTCWBiWJkf8KVSmrSPTamXa2UA)

What is wrong with this notation? How can I make Typescript to properly calculate those properties even if I use Generics?

Comment: If you would provide a https://www.typescriptlang.org/play working example it would be easier to answer the question

Comment: It's not super clear why `read<T extends QueryParamObject<Concrete>>(arg: T)` is not enough. Why you need `TExtra` to be "inferred" even though it seems to provide no additional information

Comment: @geoffrey I simplified the example. In the real project this function is in abstract class and calls an abstract method that accepts that Generic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QueryParamObject` takes an intersection of a  generic type `TExtra` and a concrete type `Concrete`. Whenever you use generic types to compute other types using mapped types or conditionals, you can't rely on the compiler to fully reason about the high level implications of those types.

In fact, most of the times, the compiler will not try to compute the result of those generic types at all, leaving us with opaque types which are often quite useless. Now given this example with a mapped type, we can see that the compiler is smart enough to not leave the type totally opaque as it at least understands that a property of `QueryParamObject` can be either `string[] | number`.

To have a satisfying conclusion, I would recommend to move the intersection.

```
function read<TExtra>(
  arg: QueryParamObject<Concrete> & QueryParamObject<TExtra>
): void {
    const arr1: string[] = arg.numberArray;
}
```

The compiler can now fully compute and understand `QueryParamObject<Concrete>` which allows accessing the three properties with the correct type. The intersection with `QueryParamObject<TExtra>` remains as a type constraint to the caller of the function.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCKBXYVEAUCGU+AtgPIBGAVsAMYwA8AKgJIB2YGMAfHALxwBvALAAoOOLgBtANbBEcAJas4sxBABmcFu04BdAFxa2HGDLm64oGMFYATAM5wAglCKJ69mFCUBzOAB84VgxicmweAH44T29WH0kLQxjfAG5RAF80kVFRJBQ4AGEIVhooYGs+QVEJIJCwqFwoCDBDYNDsLJq2+pc3VrrsBM6JZLje-EQkr18hjJyRdQwSmAViuDL8WyYAURAvfC4ACkIfQ0xsPEISCmo6eiKSsuseADJ0LBwCIjIqWgZGXb7LgASkMADcIApbFUxBIaMVPHBCFAAIxTWLxCz8E4AOm62HGiCy6SAA)

Comment: Thank you. This worked on my real project case, But instead of doing it your way I made a type casting inside the method. This is because my function is actually an implementation of the parent class

Comment: You said that 'compiler will not try...'. Is it intended behavior or this is something like a bug? Why TS cannot compute these types?

Comment: The compiler is lacking information on how to compute these types. Let's look at the mapped type: it takes `TInput` which we substituted with `Concrete & TExtra`. We know that `TExtra` is a generic type which might have any shape. The compiler would have to compute `keyof Concrete & TExtra` for the mapped type. But there is no way to know what keys `TExtra` could have. Those are determined by the caller of the function. There is simply no way to fully compute types where the input is generic and its shape is not known.

Comment: But I though then the order should play sense. Like okay, if `TExtra` goes in the end (`... & TExtra`) it is true that it can have the same properties as `Concrete`.  So when `Concrete` at the end I though TS will understand that `Concrete` takes priority and will compute types according to the end. Or am I not making sense and this order do not play any role when we speak about type intersections?

Comment: The order of types in an intersection does not make any difference. There is no priority whatsoever.